# Vue.js Firestore save geopoint

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, google-cloud-firestore

there! I am very new to Vue.js and `JavaScript` at all. I am following some youtube guide to understand how it works, but I've faced with the problem when I can't add `GeoPoint` to my Firestore database.

Here's what I have:

`firebaseInit.js`

```
import firebase from 'firebase'
import 'firebase-admin'
import firebaseConfig from './firebaseConfig'
import { scrypt } from 'crypto';
const firebaseApp = firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig)
export default firebaseApp.firestore()
```

and `script` in related `.vue` file:

```
<script>
import db from "./firebaseInit";
 ...
 greet: function(event) {
  db.collection("events_test").add({
    name: this.name,
    ...
    location: new admin.firestore.GeoPoint(51.435454, 31.445456),
    phone: this.phone
    },
    originalUrl: this.originalUrl,
    createdAt: new Date(),
    updatedAt: new Date()
  })
  .then(docRef =>{
      alert(docRef.id)
  })
  .catch(error => {
       alert(error)
  });
  <script>
```

`new admin.firestore.GeoPoint(51.435454, 31.445456)` this initialization doesn't work for me. As well as `new GeoPoint(lat,lng)` and `firebase.firestore.GeoPoint(lat,lng)`. I always get `ReferenceError` that it is not defined in `Vue.Component`. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By doing `import 'firebase-admin'` and `location: new admin.firestore.GeoPoint(51.435454, 31.445456),` you are trying to use the Admin SDK in a JavaScript/Web application (built with Vue.js).

This is not the goal of the Admin SDK which "lets you interact with Firebase **from privileged environments**", i.e. from a Server that you normally fully control. See the doc for more details: https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup and https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/

In your case you should use the "standard" JavaScript SDK to create the GeoPoint (see https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.GeoPoint) by doing:

```
<script>
import firebase from 'firebase/app'
import db from "./firebaseInit";
 ...
 greet: function(event) {
  db.collection("events_test").add({
    name: this.name,
    ...
    location: new firebase.firestore.GeoPoint(51.435454, 31.445456),
    phone: this.phone
    }
  ....
```

Note that you need to import `firebase/app` in your component.

---

Note that it seems there is an extra `{` in

```
phone: this.phone
},
originalUrl: this.originalUrl,
```

Comment: Thank you very much, @RenaudTarnec