# How to add or save from web form (Javascript) entry as GeoPoint type in Firebase Firestore

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-maps-api-3, google-cloud-firestore

Hi i have a web form which collect the following:

-cafe name
-latitude
-longitude of its location.

Currently, the lat and long is saved as map format instead of GeoPoint in Firestore.  Hence i would like to seek your advice on how it could be saved as GeoPoint format/data type.

```
form.addEventListener('submit',(e)=>{
  e.preventDefault();
  db.collection('sgcafe').add ({
    name: form.name.value,
    category: form.category.value,
    coordinates: {Latitude:form.lat.value,Longtitude:form.long.value} //save as map not Geopoint
```

I tried all the following but it does not works.

```
   coordinates: new firebase.firestore.GeoPoint(form.lat.value, form.long.value)
   coordinates: firebase.firestore.GeoPoint(form.lat.value, form.long.value)
   coordinates: GeoPoint(form.lat.value, form.long.value)
```

Answer (score 2):

If I'm right you need to send an array of coordinates to your firestore database so before the addition try this and then pass the array av value to your object's coordinates key.

```
let coords = []
coords.push(new firebase.firestore.GeoPoint(form.lat.value, form.long.value))
```

Comment: Hi babies.amas, thanks for advising, I will go and try it and get back to you. Just to check if your above code for javascript? 
 
I try looking at the reference doc for answer but couldn't find it. https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.GeoPoint

Comment: @lonelearner well you're right. That's something that I did in a project of mine but I was saving multiple points. The new firebase.firestore.GeoPoint(form.lat.value, form.long.value) should be working. Did you check if you are passing the correct lat and long?

Answer (score 1):

you're missing correct referencing to your firebase app
please see [Vue.js Firestore save geopoint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52162569/vue-js-firestore-save-geopoint)

the point you're missing is firebase import you have to import

```
import { firebase } from '@firebase/app';
```

the syntax you're using is correct

```
coordinates: new firebase.firestore.GeoPoint(form.lat.value, form.long.value)
```