# How to upload GeoPoint field type test data into Firestore database using Node.js

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, geopoints

I am using Node.js to upload test data into Firestore database. In my data set in each document I have a field that is a GeoPoint. I am unable to work out how to upload the data type: GeoPoint in the Firestore field format that can be done manually where you can enter both Latitude and Longitude as 2 seperate entries under the field type GeoPoint  . my Node.js only uploads as a single "String"

Any help with my code would be appreciated.. !

Refer: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/node/firebase.firestore.GeoPoint

```
const admin = require('./node_modules/firebase-admin');
const serviceAccount = require("./**ServiceAccount**.json");

const data = require("./csvjson.json");
const collectionKey = "towns"; //name of the collection

admin.initializeApp({
  credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
  databaseURL: "**DatebaseURL**.com"
});

const firestore = admin.firestore();
const settings = {timestampsInSnapshots: true};
firestore.settings(settings);

if (data && (typeof data === "object")) {
    Object.keys(data).forEach(docKey => {
    firestore
        .collection(collectionKey)
        .doc()
        .set(data[docKey])
        .then((res) => {
            console.log("Document " + docKey + " successfully written!");
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.error("Error writing document: ", error);
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: You should be able to set a point in a document as shown here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62103613, likely then using `new admin.firestore.GeoPoint(latvalue, lonvalue)`.

Answer (score 0):

Adding member comment as Community Wiki for better visibility.

The creation of Firestore GeoPoint objects is documented [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/GeoPoint). Moreover you could find code samples in the [API documentation](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/firestore/latest/GeoPoint.html) for Firestore.

You might also take a look at this other [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62103613).